# CXF Url Encoding on a client side

Tags: java, http, jax-rs, cxf

How to disable url encoding on a client side using CXF
For example

```
 restClient.sendRequest("myemail@ololo.com")
```

Will be converted to

```
Address: http://myhost.com/endpoint?email=myemail%40ololo.com
Http-Method: DELETE
Content-Type: application/xml
Headers: {Content-Type=[application/xml], Accept=[application/xml]}
```

How can I configure my client to disable that?

Comment: Because the endpoint does not decode incoming requests.

Comment: Is that possible to send @ as a query parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any URL you can find, certain characters are special and must be escaped before forming the URI (See [RFC 2396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396))

> ```
> reserved    = ";" | "/" | "?" | ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" | "+" |
> ```

```
                "$" | ","
```

It means you have to send the `@` character as `%40` in the URL.

If you want to send `@` unescaped do not use a Query parameter. Use a POST request with the desired content in the body of the payload and a text content-type such as `text/plain` or `application/xml` (do not use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`)